# default date and time for DateTimeField in django

Tags: python, django

in my models, I have :

```
date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

This is surely works and adds current date and time for new records that get created.

However, I want to set the default date and time for existing records as `01/01/2020 00:00:01`.

if I try to add a default along with auto_now, I get an error stating auto_now and default are mutually exclusive.

Comment: You're adding this field retroactively and you want to update records already in the database which don't have that field yet…? That's an issue for *migrations* then, not the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding this field now, you'll need two migration steps.

First, add

```
date_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

and run `makemigrations`. Django will ask you what to use for the default; tell it you'll want `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)`.

Then modify the field to

```
date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and run `makemigrations` again.